# Corba in Glassfish?

Tags: corba

This is probably a stupid question. I have an extremely old VisiBroker CORBA application. I need to rewrite it IN CORBA (no web services, EJB, etc). Is there a way to run a CORBA application in Glassfish (3.1.1) I see it has the ORB configuration to set the thread pool and all but I guess this is just used for EJBs.

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish supports CORBA. But what has GlassFish to do with your application when you do not need Java EE?